# Pycharm and Webstorm always on top unless minimized

Tags: windows-7, webstorm

I'm running Windows 7. I have the following problem in both Webstorm 7 and Pycharm 3. I haven't found this problem in any other programs. I have not found any clues as to a solution on Google or in the settings of either program.

When I run the programs not maximized and I click any other window to switch focus, the Webstorm (or Pycharm) window flashes, appearing to lose focus for a split second before, and it stays on top. This blocks any other window behind it from having focus, and is quite annoying.

Comment: please vote for [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114594)

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I should either delete this question, or your comment should be the accepted answer, since it is the closest to a solution I'll be able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug, please vote for [IDEA-114594](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114594)